# Can Bash Variable Expansion be performed directly on user input?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, variable-substitution, read

In bash, is there any way to read in user input but still allow `bash` variable expansion?

I am trying to request the user enter a path in the middle of a program but since `~` and other variables are not expanded as a part of the `read` builtin, users have to enter in an absolute path.

Example: When a user enters a path into:

```
read -ep "input> " dirin
  [[ -d "$dirin" ]]
```

returns true when a user enters `/home/user/bin` but not `~/bin` or `$HOME/bin`.

Comment: The Bash manual provides [an example of manually implementing tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#A-Programmable-Completion-Example) using `eval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive way would be:

```
eval "dirin=$dirin"
```

What that does is evaluate the expansion of `dirin=$dirin` as shell code.

With `dirin` containing `~/foo`, it's actually evaluating:

```
dirin=~/foo
```

It's easy to see the limitations. With a `dirin` containing `foo bar`, that becomes:

```
dirin=foo bar
```

So it's running `bar` with `dirin=foo` in its environment (and you'd have other problems with all the shell special characters).

Here, you'd need to decide what expansions are allowed (tilde, command substitution, parameter expansion, process substitution, arithmetic expansion, filename expansion...) and either do those substitutions by hand, or use `eval` but *escape* every character but those that would allow them which would be virtually impossible other than by implementing  a full shell syntax parser unless you limit it to for instance `~foo`, `$VAR`, `${VAR}`.

Here, I'd use `zsh` instead of `bash` that has a dedicated operator for that:

```
vared -cp "input> " dirin
printf "%s\n" "${(e)dirin}"
```

`vared` is the *variable editor*, similar to `bash`'s `read -e`.

`(e)` is a parameter expansion flag that performs expansions (parameter, command, arithmetic but not tilde) in the content of the parameter.

To address tilde expansion, which only takes place at the beginning of the string, we'd do:

```
vared -cp "input> " dirin
if [[ $dirin =~ '^(~[[:alnum:]_.-]*(/|$))(.*)' ]]; then
  eval "dirin=$match[1]\${(e)match[3]}"
else
  dirin=${(e)dirin}
fi
```

POSIXly (so `bash`ly as well), to perform tilde and variable (not parameter) expansion, you could write a function like:

```
expand_var() {
  eval "_ev_var=\${$1}"
  _ev_outvar=
  _ev_v=${_ev_var%%/*}
  case $_ev_v in
    (?*[![:alnum:]._-]*) ;;
    ("~"*)
      eval "_ev_outvar=$_ev_v"; _ev_var=${_ev_var#"$_ev_v"}
  esac

  while :; do
    case $_ev_var in
      (*'$'*)
        _ev_outvar=$_ev_outvar${_ev_var%%"$"*}
        _ev_var=${_ev_var#*"$"}
        case $_ev_var in
          ('{'*'}'*)
            _ev_v=${_ev_var%%\}*}
            _ev_v=${_ev_v#"{"}
            case $_ev_v in
              "" | [![:alpha:]_]* | *[![:alnum:]_]*) _ev_outvar=$_ev_outvar\$ ;;
              (*) eval "_ev_outvar=\$_ev_outvar\${$_ev_v}"; _ev_var=${_ev_var#*\}};;
            esac;;
          ([[:alpha:]_]*)
            _ev_v=${_ev_var%%[![:alnum:]_]*}
            eval "_ev_outvar=\$_ev_outvar\$$_ev_v"
            _ev_var=${_ev_var#"$_ev_v"};;
          (*)
            _ev_outvar=$_ev_outvar\$
        esac;;
      (*)
        _ev_outvar=$_ev_outvar$_ev_var
        break
    esac
  done
  eval "$1=\$_ev_outvar"
}
```

Example:

```
$ var='~mail/$USER'
$ expand_var var;
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
/var/mail/stephane
```

As an approximation, we could also prepend every character but `~${}-_.` and alnums with backslash before passing to `eval`:

```
eval "dirin=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$dirin" |
    sed 's/[^[:alnum:]~${}_.-]/\\&/g')"
```

(here simplified on the ground that `$dirin` can't contain newline characters as it comes from `read`)

That would trigger syntax errors if one entered `${foo#bar}` for instance but at least that can't do much harm as a simple `eval` would.

**Edit**: a working solution for `bash` and other POSIX shells would be to separate the tilde and other expansions like in `zsh` and use `eval` with a here-document for the *other expansions* part like:

```
expand_var() {
  eval "_ev_var=\${$1}"
  _ev_outvar=
  _ev_v=${_ev_var%%/*}
  case $_ev_v in
    (?*[![:alnum:]._-]*) ;;
    ("~"*)
      eval "_ev_outvar=$_ev_v"; _ev_var=${_ev_var#"$_ev_v"}
  esac
  eval "$1=\$_ev_outvar\$(cat << //unlikely//
$_ev_var
//unlikely//
)"
```

That would allow tilde, parameter, arithmetic and command expansions like in `zsh` above.
    }